# Device Guard Code Integrity policy pop-up "Invalid Public Key Security Object File"

Tags: uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I have already followed the instructions ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s)) on renaming the desired policy file to `SIPolicy.P7B`, and copying it into the `C:\Windows\System32\CodeIntegrity\`.

However, when I tried to open/execute the policy files this pop-up appears.
[Pop-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CL1j.png)

I want to clarify if this is normal. 
Should I just ignore this pop-up and restart my machine? Or is the file corrupted/broken?

My machine's OS is `Windows 10 Pro version 1803 (Build 17134.441)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Link to the answer from the Microsoft Forum](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6ec11d36-7544-4527-a65c-983b465a797e/unable-to-install-the-device-guard-code-integrity-policies?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues)

The error pop-up is just the normal behavior when you try to open/execute the file.
Ignore the error pop-up and proceed in restarting your machine for the policy file to be installed.